# Javascript: Is there a special way to evaluate float numbers? My result is inconsistent

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I'm making a code to change the value of something based on the range it is in. I notice that there's an inconsistency when using decimals and negative numbers which is a must in my application.

But at least, i wanted to share this problem to check if this is common knowledge and i'm missing something.

```
level = -1;
   if (level < 0.01) {
      level = 'a';
   }
   if (level < 0) {
      level = 'b';
   }
   console.log(level);
```

Expected result: 'b'

Result: 'a'

Removing negative numbers seems to no change anything, changing the float number to an int number doesn't change anything also. It seems that if the first "if clause" is validated, the second one is skipped for some reason.

Comment: why are you assigning the variable to a string after checking it's value? It would likely be easier to have them be separate values

Answer (score 1):

The first condition (`level < 0.01`) is true, as `-1` is less than `0.01`. So the block for that `if` statement runs and `level` is set to `'a'`.

The next condition (`level < 0`) is equivalent to `'a' < 0`, which is false. It is not skipped; it is just that the condition no longer matches since `level` was modified by the previous `if` statement.

In this case, you should switch around the order if statements and make use of `else`.

```js
if (level < 0) {
    level = 'b';
} else if (level < 0.01) {
    level = 'a';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

#### The order of *your* "if"s matters

I think you have been unwise to modify the *input* variable, rather than generate a new *output* variable.

Once your first `if` changes the value of `level`, the original value of `level` is no longer available to be tested.

One fix would be to reverse the order of the "if" statements. However that does not fix the fundamental problem: confusing the input and output variables.

#### It would be better to have separate input and output variables

This allows you:

- to keep your original ordering of `if`s
- to test `level` multiple times, without its value being destroyed

In general separating input and output variables is a good plan. Separating variables of different types is also a good plan. So this arrangement is good from both points of view.

```js
level = -1;
if (level < 0.01) {
  output = 'a';
}
if (level < 0) {
  output = 'b';
}
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score -1):

@Unmitigated is spot on.

I just want to iterate a little on

> since level was modified by the previous if statement.

General rule is to avaoid reassigning variables and use const for variables. In your case value can be a number or a letter. Meaning you have no idea what you are working with. You also use multiple if statements instead of if else, meaning both can trigger.

```
const level = -1;
let result;
if (level < 0) {
    result = 'b';
} else if (level < 0.01) {
    result = 'a';
}

console.log(result)
```